# App fails in release mode. How to know why?

Tags: android, windows, react-native

I have 2 days of react-native experience and just learned how to build & install app to real device. I signed up apk with key.
executing of:

```
react-native run-android
```

works fine on real device, i even can't see any errors in remote debugger
but launching

```
gradlew installRelease  // or 
gradlew assembleRelease // plus manually installation
```

== Unfortunately, App has stopped.

P.S. i can't share code, because it's under NDA, but i use only

```
redux, react-native-router-flux
```

and have only 2 simple pages

**UP**
after launching installation commit after commit starting from empty project, i have found, commit that breaks app on release on device:

1. i added `.babelrc:

   "presets": [
      "es2015",
       "stage-0",
       "react-native"
      ]
   }`
2. installed new packages for tests:

   `"babel-core": "6.11.4",
   "babel-loader": "6.2.4",
   "babel-preset-es2015": "6.9.0",
   "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.0",
   "babel-preset-stage-0": "6.5.0",
   "chai": "3.5.0",
   "enzyme": "2.4.1",
   "eslint-plugin-react": "5.2.2",
   "mocha": "2.5.3",
   "mockery": "1.7.0",
   "react-addons-test-utils": "15.2.1",
   "react-dom": "15.2.1",
   "react-native-mock": "0.2.5"`

Comment: can you share the build log ?

Comment: @BertrandMartel please check `gradlew assembleRelease --info`
https://gist.github.com/olegkalyta/dfe34d4dad5d322c0bdacd5003758311

Answer (score 0):

After removing 
`"es2015", "stage-0"` from `.babelrc` app started work on real device also. It would be good to understand why :)